# Get contents of text file in java?

Tags: java, file-io, text-files

I have a simple problem.
I wrote a method in java to get the contents of text file.

```
public static String[] viewSuppliers()
{
    Scanner x = null;
    try{
        x = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\suppliers.txt"));
        while(x.hasNext())
        {
            String a = x.next();
            String b = x.next();
            String c = x.next();
            String d = x.next();
            String array[] = {a,b,c,d};
            return array;
        }
        x.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I have called this method in main program but it only returns one line of the file. The contents of my text file are like this:

```
PEPSI John London 214222
COLA Sarah France 478800
```

Here is my main program:

```
String array3[] = {"Supplier Company: ", "Supplier Name: ", "Supplier Address: ", 
    "Supplier Phone Number: "};
String array4[] = i.viewSuppliers(); // object of class
if(i.viewSuppliers() == null)
    System.out.println("No current suppliers.");
else
{
    System.out.println("Current Suppliers: ");
    for(int u = 0; u < array3.length; u++)
    {
        System.out.printf(array3[u]);
        System.out.println(array4[u]);
    }
}
```

When i run the main program and call the method it is only return the first line and i want to return all the file.

Comment: You are returning your array at the end of the first iteration, which is causing it to only process the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning an array of 4 strings,
it seems what you really want is to return a list of array of 4 strings:

```
public static List<String[]> viewSuppliers()
{
    List<String[]> lines = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner x = null;
    try{
        x = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\فاطمة\\Downloads\\suppliers.txt"));
        while(x.hasNext())
        {
            String a = x.next();
            String b = x.next();
            String c = x.next();
            String d = x.next();
            String array[] = {a,b,c,d};
            lines.add(array);
        }
        x.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Then, iterate over the results:

```
List<String[]> list = i.viewSuppliers(); // object of class
if (list.isEmpty())
    System.out.println("No current suppliers.");
else
{
    System.out.println("Current Suppliers: ");
    for (String[] supplier : list) {
        for(int u = 0; u < array3.length; u++)
        {
            System.out.printf(array3[u]);
            System.out.println(supplier[u]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try take the return out of the while loop, otherwise after the first iteration it returns.

Comment: yes i tried this, but the problem is that the array takes its arguments from inside the while loop, when returned outside it shows me that array are not declared.

Answer (score 0):

You have the output on a loop based on the length of array3, but not array4, so it will always only print the first supplier because of the length of array3.

```
    System.out.println("Current Suppliers: ");
for(int u = 0; u < array3.length; u++)
{
    System.out.printf(array3[u]);
    System.out.println(array4[u]);
}
```

Perhaps adding the System.out.println(array4) to a loop based on its length below the first loop.